# how do I get my hp 100 printer to work

Tags: bluetooth

just installed ubuntu, and my hp100 Bluetooth printer is recognized, but it will not allow me to turn the connection on and print. any solutions would be very appreciated

Comment: Hard to say, try `apt-get install hplip printer-driver-hpijs`

Comment: would love to try that, but being completely new to this type of OS, and being out of computers for years, I wouldn't know where to start

Comment: run that command with `sudo` in a terminal

Comment: nvm, I'll just wire the sum beech up. sorry this layman wasted your time, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)**

Just go to the software center and search hplip

[image]

The basic packages may already be installed, Make sure to scroll down and check the extras!

Comment: thanks for the description as to how to get this thing working. it works and it is very much appreciated

Comment: No problem please remember to close  the question by clicking the ChecKMarK!!