# HP colour laser network printing with 14.0.4

Tags: printing

I am a relatively new convert to Ubuntu but the one thing that doesn't seem too easy is setting up network printing (HP colour laser printer with scanner etc) as all I get is error messages with the various pieces of software I am supposed to add in. hplip-3.16.2.run is just a full list of failures and it isn't clear what is missing? Have I just confused myself or am I too stupid to do it? I only have 35 years in IT to fall back on but I am ancient!

Comment: HP printers are mostly easy to set up(?). If any company HP is the one that has the most love for Linux. If you get any errors you will need to add them into the question for us to be able to help.

Comment: New hp printers with scanners need the extras in "hplip"  http://askubuntu.com/questions/726054/how-do-i-get-my-hp-100-printer-to-work/726088#726088